# How to check array of Pending Intents in Espresso?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-espresso, android-pendingintent

I know how to check single intent using:

```
Intents.intended(IntentMatchers.hasComponent(Activity::class.java.name))
```

I need to check an array of intents, any help is appreciated.